# How to add newline between the 2 objects in JSON response ? And also how to remove the [ ] square brackets from the json file?

Tags: java, json, file, newline, printwriter

I tried using **line.separator** and **\n** as well. But its not working.
Here is my code :

```
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        JSONArray json = new JSONArray();
        while (rs.next()) {
            int numColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            for (int i = 1; i <= numColumns; i++) {
                String column_name = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
                obj.put(column_name, rs.getObject(column_name));
            }

            json.put(obj);
        }
        PrintWriter file = new PrintWriter("JFile.json");
            file.println(json);
            file.close();

    } catch (SQLException | FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Edit 1
Here is the updated code with the JSONObject, also adding indentfactor in the object shows **com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.JsonEOFException: Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Object**:

```
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        while (rs.next()) {
            int numColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
            for (int i = 1; i <= numColumns; i++) {
                String column_name = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
                obj.put(column_name, rs.getObject(column_name));
            }
        }
        PrintWriter file = new PrintWriter("downloads/JSONFile.json");
        file.println(obj.toString());
        file.close();
    } catch (SQLException | FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213391/discussion-on-question-by-aka-gk-how-to-add-newline-between-the-2-objects-in-jso).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray();
while (rs.next()) {
    int numColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    for (int i = 1; i <= numColumns; i++) {
           String column_name = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
           obj.put(column_name, rs.getObject(column_name));
        }
        jsonArr.put(obj);
   }        
//add this JSONArray to another JSONObject 
JSONObject rootJSONObject = new JSONObject();
rootJSONObject.put("data",jsonArr);

PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter("sample.json");
printWriter.write(rootJSONObject.toString(4).replace("{", "\n{\n").replace("}", "\n}\n"));
printWriter.close();
```

Comment: In JSONObject , json.put(obj)  requires 2 fields. I tried using JSONObject but it gives me some escape sequence charcters in output ...  {"{\"Employee_Name\":\" Sammy     \",\"Employeee_NBR\":\"938501\"}"}